# Unterminated Regex Linux

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to replace text that matches a Regex with space. The command I am trying to run is:

```
sed -i '(\[^\x00-\x7F^\p{L}\]+)/ /g' abc.txt
```

The error Im receiving is 
    sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated address regex.

I have escaped the [,] with \ [ and \ ] and still the same error. Need your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the first `/` for the replacement command. You could try something like:

```
sed 's/(\[^\x00-\x7F^\p{L}\]+)/ /g' abc.txt
```

Or at least it might give you an idea.

Comment: the command is working fine with no errors but the output is not as expected.  I need to replace the � with space in 'möchte \�Mann\� gar'. The above command retains everything.

Comment: You should paste part of your `abc.txt` file in your question and then say what you really want with your regex. ;)